# Get multiple results on my query

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have following table structure,

```
mysql> select * from purchase_order_detail;
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
| purchase_order_detail_id | purchase_order_id | item_id | ordered_quantity | created_by              | created_on          | updated_by | updated_on          |
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
|                        1 |                 1 |     279 |              100 | NULL                    | 2015-02-21 01:42:06 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:42:06 |
|                        2 |                 1 |     286 |              100 | NULL                    | 2015-02-21 01:42:06 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:42:06 |
|                        3 |                 2 |     279 |              200 | NULL                    | 2015-02-21 01:42:34 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:42:34 |
|                        4 |                 2 |     286 |              300 | NULL                    | 2015-02-21 01:42:34 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:42:34 |
|                       23 |                 1 |     287 |              100 | taqi.official@gmail.com | 2015-02-22 14:37:04 | NULL       | 2015-02-22 14:37:04 |
|                       24 |                28 |     286 |               43 | admin@gmail.com         | 2015-02-22 18:10:15 | NULL       | 2015-02-22 18:10:15 |
|                       25 |                28 |     287 |               43 | admin@gmail.com         | 2015-02-22 18:10:23 | NULL       | 2015-02-22 18:10:23 |
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from delivery_order;
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
| delivery_order_id | purchase_order_detail_id | recieved_quantity | recieved_on         | created_by      | created_on          | updated_by | updated_on          |
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
|                 1 |                        1 |                50 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL            | 2015-02-21 01:44:15 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:44:15 |
|                 2 |                        2 |                50 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL            | 2015-02-21 01:44:15 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:44:15 |
|                 3 |                        1 |                50 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL            | 2015-02-21 01:44:35 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:44:35 |
|                 4 |                        3 |                70 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL            | 2015-02-21 01:44:35 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:44:35 |
|                 5 |                        4 |               150 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL            | 2015-02-21 01:45:04 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:45:04 |
|                 6 |                        3 |                90 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL            | 2015-02-21 01:45:04 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:45:04 |
|                 7 |                        4 |               100 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NULL            | 2015-02-21 01:45:28 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:45:28 |
|                28 |                       24 |                34 | 2015-02-21 00:00:00 | admin@gmail.com | 2015-02-22 18:10:15 | NULL       | 2015-02-22 18:10:15 |
|                29 |                       25 |                34 | 2015-02-21 00:00:00 | admin@gmail.com | 2015-02-22 18:10:23 | NULL       | 2015-02-22 18:10:23 |
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from stock;
+----------+-------------------+------------+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
| stock_id | delivery_order_id | project_id | quantity | stock_type_id | created_by | created_on          | updated_by | updated_on          |
+----------+-------------------+------------+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
|        1 |                 1 |          1 |       30 |             1 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:46:38 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:46:38 |
|        2 |                 1 |          2 |       20 |             1 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:46:38 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:46:38 |
|        3 |                 2 |          1 |       50 |             1 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:47:30 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:47:30 |
|        4 |                 3 |          1 |       40 |             1 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:47:30 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:47:30 |
|        5 |                 3 |          2 |       10 |             1 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:47:51 | NULL       | 2015-02-21 01:47:51 |
+----------+-------------------+------------+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
```

and i want to get all stock_id where purchase_order_id = 1 and item_id = 279.
i have written this query

```
select s.stock_id 
  from stock s
     , delivery_order do
     , purchase_order_detail pod
     , purchase_order po 
 where s.delivery_order_id = do.delivery_order_id
   and pod.purchase_order_detail_id = do.purchase_order_detail_id
   and po.purchase_order_id = 1 
   and pod.item_id = 279;
```

but get below result, which is incorrect...

```
+----------+
| stock_id |
+----------+
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        4 |
|        5 |
+----------+
```

i wanted to get stock_id of against specific purchase_order_id and item_id in purchase_order_detail table.

Comment: Does po relate to the other tables in some way?

Comment: yes, it is one to many from top to bottom.

Comment: `purchase_order` is one to many to `purchase_order_detail`. `purchase_order_detail`is one to many to `delivery_order` . `delivery_order` is one to many to `stock`

Comment: You might like to include that information in your Structured Query!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  s.stock_id ID
FROM stock s 
  LEFT JOIN delivery_order do 
    ON s.delivery_order_id = do.delivery_order_id
  LEFT JOIN purchase_order_detail pod 
    ON do.purchase_order_detail_id = pod.purchase_order_detail_id
WHERE pod.purchase_order_id = 1 
   AND pod.item_id = 279;
```